# NetBeans - JComboBox warning - missing type arguments for generic class JComboBox<E>

Tags: swing, warnings, netbeans-7, jcombobox, matisse

I am using NetBeans IDE 7.1.2. When I compile my application I get the following warning:

> warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: JComboBox
>           city = new javax.swing.JComboBox();   missing type arguments for generic class JComboBox   where E is a type-variable:
>       E extends Object declared in class JComboBox

So, I guess I have to declare the JComboBox as:

```
JComboBox<String> city = new JComboBox<String>();
```

But how do I do this in NetBeans, using the Matisse (Swing GUI Builder)? Please help.

Answer (score 17):

In Netbeans 7.2 you can click on Code section for JComboBox, and then write type into "Type Parameters", in your case: `<String>`.

Comment: This helped, just one small improvement to clarify how to get to the code section: right-click the JComboBox, choose _Properties_, select the _Code_ section (at the top of the properties window). _Type Parameters_ is close to the top.

Comment: @chr and remember to write the type parameter _including_ the angle brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 introduced generics to the `JComboBox`.  One solution to your problem would be to ust Java 6.

I'd bet the latest version of Netbeans (7.2) will have a solution for this (although I'm not positive).

Otherwise, if I remember right, you can view the code generated by Netbeans.  If so, you may be able to add the generic arguement yourself.  It's been many months since I tinkered with Netbeans though...

Also, if the Netbeans allows you to, you can add the `@SupressesWarnings` annotation above the `JComboBox` declaration (or even above the class declaration, although that changes it's scope).  It would be something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
JComboBox city = new JComboBox();
```

There are lots of options, but Netbeans may hold you back from implementing some of them.

Comment: Nick I tried to change the code to: city = new javax.swing.JComboBox<String>(); (NetBeans does not allow me to change the declaration variables therefore my city is defined as private javax.swing.JComboBox city;). When I did this I get the following warning: redundant type arguments in new expression (use diamond operator instead).

Comment: I'm not sure you'll be able to get around the warning then without downgrading your Java version or updating your Netbeans IDE.  Fortunately, it's just a warning so it won't affect your actual code.  If it bothers you, you can try adding this line above your declaration:  `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")`  I'll add this to the answer as well.  I don't know of a way to turn compiler warnings off in Netbeans - someone else may know.

Comment: Thank you very much Nick. At least now I know that I am not doing anything wrong as per coding. I hope this is fixed in the v7.2, I haven't tried it yet, waiting for oracle to release it with JDK.